# Combobox selection from Database

Tags: c#, database, wpf, combobox, connection

I have a question about showing a ComboBox with items from my Database.

What I've got:

I have a Table called "Product" with Column's "Id" and "Name"

In my Visual Studio XAML I have a ComboBox:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Product}"  Margin="42,74,364,615" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
```

And in C# I have the following code

```
     private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM [Product]";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        comboBox.ItemsSource();
        con.Close();
    }
```

I don't get any Items in my ComboBox and also I don't get an Error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *don't get any Items in my ComboBox* - so we can better understand how you think about code/how the black box of data access in front of you works, please tell us: which line of code that you have written do you think puts items in the combo? And which other line of code does that line of code get them from? Getting things from a DB and showing them in a UI is typically a process of: download the items from the DB into a local temporary store of data in memory, link the temporary store to the UI widget so that it will read and display them. Which of your lines of code do this?

Comment: Also, do you really have no errors when you try to compile this code? ItemsSource is a property not a method.

Comment: Side point: you are missing `using` statements. Also you can condense the code by passing the connString and SQL in the constructors

Comment: Thank you for awnsering. It is a good question Caius and I will research it. I'm a beginner in WPF C# for my studie. It's my first project so it's a good question which line of code i think the items will put in.